# Why recursively-bound inheritance is not allowed in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance

I am trying to create a base class as follows:

```
open class ManagedObject<Entity: NSManagedObject>: NSManagedObject{
    
}
```

then use it as:

```
class LocalEntity: ManagedObject<LocalEntity>{
    
}
```

And it gives me an error:

> 'LocalEntity' inherits from itself
>
> 'ManagedObject' requires that 'LocalEntity' inherit from
> 'NSManagedObject'

I do not really get why I am getting such error. This looks totally valid inheritance case. I would be happy if anyone would give me a source to read or explain why it is not allowed to do this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585). I suspect what you are really asking is, "what feature(s) of Swift makes recursive bound inheritance harder/impossible to implement, compared to languages such as Java/C#, which do have recursive bound inheritance?" If that is what you are asking, please edit.

Comment: @Sweeper I am starting to learn Swift and trying to understand why it is not possible. I am not saying it should be there but it is not there. Just trying to understand the rationale behind the decision. The question is not clear it basically says "why". Generics in Swift are not defined as it is defined in Kotlin, for example and I would not ask why it is so but if there were not generics at all I would ask for reason behind the language design or resource that language architects specify the reason

Comment: Note that if you pick a random "why is (any specific thing) not implemented in (any specific language)" out of a hat, the correct answer will be "because no one has implemented it," or possibly "it's never come up in our design discussions" rather than there being some explicit document stating the precise reason it's was rejected. This often makes "why" questions difficult to answer on Stack Overflow, and better posed directly to the forums (forums.swift.org) where the developers are. SO is much better at "HOW do I do this concrete thing" than "WHY does this abstract thing not exist?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a [compiler bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/55714). If you have a practical use for it, I recommend commenting on the issue.

Comment: Checked the issue, looks like they do not even give a s*ht about it. Related issues have been around, at least, 3 years and they are just sitting there. I do not think adding practical usage would make much difference to kick-off the task. If you check the related tasks, you can see they actually acknowledge this as a problem and have done almost nothing about it

Comment: I would say then that adding practical usage is *exactly* would would make a difference. I've been programming in Swift since Swift came out, and have never run into this bug (didn't know it existed until you asked and I looked it up). Having people who it's actually causing serious problems for is exactly how things get prioritized.

Comment: (As a rule, subclassing is discouraged in Swift, preferring composition rather than inheritance. When you merge subclasses and generics, and especially if you merge those with protocols, you will more often bump into weird bugs. I can't see in your code why LocalEntity is a subclass at all rather than just at typealias, which wouldn't have this problem.)

Comment: I am just trying to have generic function for Core Data entities in base class without repeating myself (constructors, fetch requests). I come from Kotlin and I have seen lots of drawbacks in Swift that makes things really complicated. This is my subjective opinion, of course. Just another off-topic note, PATs are like they were designed by some intern and not by language architect. Anyway, thanks for advice and follow-ups

Comment: Generic shared functions are added much more elegantly with extensions. There is no need for subclasses just to add more methods. The only reason for subclasses is when you need to perform overrides of a class that provides customization via override points. (That's common in ObjC, so Swift imports some of it, but it's rare in Swift, so inheritance is rare in Swift.)

Comment: Kotlin is nice. I generally enjoy it. I also often run into things where I shout "are you kidding me? This is so easy in Swift! Why do I have to create an entire new class just for this?!?!?"

Comment: Right, sometimes I am as shocked as you are, honestly, haha. And yes, at the end I went with the extensions, actually